# Why PHP can't write even with chmod 777 and SELinux disabled?

Tags: php, chmod, selinux, nextcloud

### Problem

PHP can't write files. Function `is_writable('/data')` return `false`

#### Details:

When I'm trying to install NextCloud and setting it's data directory to `/data`, I meet the `Can't create or write into the data directory` error. Following it, I find `is_writable($dataDir)` failed (`/path/to/nextcloud/lib/private/setup.php` line `312`)

I have set `chmod 777 -R /data` and `chown -R www:www /data` and SELinux disabled.

Is it a problem with `open_basedir` inside `php.ini`, or any other reason?

### Platform

- CentOS 8
- LNMP with php7.3 installed by [BT-Panel](http://bt.cn)

  - nginx 1.61
  - php 7.3

Comment: Apache Server user is `www-data`. I am not sure about the user `www`. Which Server you are using?

Comment: @HarishST I'm using nginx

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem myself

**There are many php.ini files!** Please check if any of them contains `open_basedir`. If `open_basedir` is set, php write access will be limited.

Read more about [open_basedir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir)